# How to run python 2.7 code in a 3.6 enviorment

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.6

I am trying to use python to set my Windows 10 desktop image. The following code works fine when I run it in 2.7:

`import ctypes
import os`

`SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20`
`ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "C:\Users\dzure\Desktop\stuff\imgs\IMG_impr.JPG", 3)`
`#'C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\abc.jpg'`

However this code doesn't work in 3.6. I already tried using 2to3 but the code just sets the desktop to solid black and not the image. So I want to know if there is a way to put this code in a python 3 function and have it treated as python 2 code, or just a way to get a working result in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found my answer. basically I took this code:

```
reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d C:\Users\dzure\Desktop\stuff\imgs\b23.bmp
```

`RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True`
and made that a .bat file. I then took that file and simply:

```
imp ort os
q = 0
while q < 10:
          os.system('set.bat')
          q += 1
```

Sometimes the bat file doesn't work so that's why I added the while loop.